# jScrollPane with smooth effect

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, smoothing

I use jScrollPane plugin and my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="sourcecode">
  $(function()
  {
  $('#mycontent').jScrollPane();
});
</script>
```

And it's work. But i want add smooth effect my scrollbar. How can i do like this? http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/custom-scrollbar-plugin/fluid_scrollbar_example.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a transition to 'top' css property to .jspDrag

```
.jspDrag{
    transition: top 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

It works only for scrollbar,
for content you can do the same with .jspPane but it's buggy with mouseWheel

so I suggest to use another library supporting smooth scroll :

- Nice scroll : http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html
- Custom content scroller : http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: Transitions are not supported by Internet Explorer: http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: Sorry, it's working now, thanks but content isn't transition... And true class not jspTrack, it's jspDrag

Comment: for content, you can do the same with `.jspPane` but it's buggy with mouse wheel